# Deleting Specific Object From Core Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my Core Data Entity `Favorite`, I am appending Strings to its Attribute `fav`.

When I look up a `fav` object based on String name and try to **delete** it, it is not deleting the entry, but instead is setting that object's `fav = nil`

Here is my code:

```
let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
let favoriteFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Favorite")

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fav == %@", "snowboarding")

   favoriteFetchRequest.predicate = predicate

let fetchedEntities = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(favoriteFetchRequest, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]

    for entity in fetchedEntities {
       managedContext.deleteObject(entity)

       if !managedContext.save(&error) {
          println("Could not save \(error)")
       }
    }
```

When I rerun the app and have all Entity data display, the log shows:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7fc8b0d1e4f0> (entity: Favorite; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://8984EF48-71AF-4B87-AA59-EE5999038369/Favorite/p2> ; data: {
fav = nil;})
```

This is turn creates a whole bunch of `nil` entries and the Core Data is never empty (as I'd like it to be at times). What am I doing wrong? How do I delete the entire object?

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you **save** the managed object context after deleting the objects?

Comment: @MartinR, yes I am saving it. I have added it to the above code. That is why it has "successfully" (although not intended) changed the `fav = snowboarding` to `fav = nil` and has persisted after app relaunch as well :(

Comment: Can you edit the original post to show a little more of the code, namely the whole function that finds, deletes, and saves the CoreData objects?  From what I can tell, it looks correct, but it may the ordering of things that is a little off, so posting the whole code snippet with the save function included might help.

Comment: @PD1ce, I have modified to to show how I am finding it with `NSPredicate`, deleting it with `deleteObject` and then saving it with `.save()`. That is pretty much the order that it is going in. Objects just keep turning into `nil` instead of being removed.

Comment: Great, I'm going to add an answer and see if that helps, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I do anything with `CoreData`, I take care of all the transactions before saving.  Adding new `Entities`, saving new `Entity` attributes, etc. (Well, I shouldn't say *all*, but in most cases when I'm doing an update)

I'm not sure if this will fix it but try moving your

```
if !managedContext.save(&error) {
    println("Could not save \(error)")
}
```

Out of the `for` loop and instead have it read:

```
for entity in fetchedEntities {
    managedContext.deleteObject(entity)
}
if !managedContext.save(&error) {
    println("Could not save \(error)")
}
```

The rest of the code looks fine so this is the only thing I can blatantly see that differs from how I usually update my `CoreData` entries.  Let me know if that solves anything.

EDIT: A little bug investigation you could as well is after the `for` loop, access the `managedContext`'s `deletedObjects` property and check the `count` of that `NSSet` and see if it is actually registering those objects to be deleted.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it is still turning those entries into `fav = nil`. I checked the log for what would be deleted and it indeed shows the correct object to be deleted... LOG: `DELETED OBJECTS -  [<NSManagedObject: 0x7fab19665d50> (entity: Favorite; id: 0xd0000000001c0000 <x-coredata://E792D94E-B247-463A-9F4A-7886B8A8D052/Favorite/p7> ; data: {
    fav = snowboarding;
})]`

Comment: on a side note (and as an alternative), do you know how to clear out and delete **all** objects under `fav` in Core Data to make it empty? Thinking of doing this as a workaround...